# RecyclerView fling and item click

Tags: java, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, android-touch-event

I have a `RecyclerView` that has a grid of items. Upon clicking on an item, it highlights.
I also want that when the user swipes right the a 'next' method is called, and when the user swipes left, a 'previous' method is called.
However, the two don't work out with each other, as each intercepts the other's events.
How do I get them to work together?

This is my code:

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        myHolder = holder as MyView;
        myHolder.mMainView.SetOnClickListener(this);
        if (selected_position == position)
        {
            holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGray);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
        }
   }

public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        int position = mRecyclerView.GetChildLayoutPosition((View)sender);

        // Updating old as well as new positions
        NotifyItemChanged(selected_position);
        selected_position = position;
        NotifyItemChanged(selected_position);
    }
```

**Fragment that contains the RecyclerView**

```
calendarRecyclerView.SetOnTouchListener(this);

public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                x1 = e.GetX();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                x2 = e.GetX();
                float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                {
                    // Left to Right swipe action
                    if (x2 > x1)
                    {
                        NextMonth();
                    }

                    // Right to left swipe action               
                    else
                    {
                        PreviousMonth();
                    }
                }


                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Because I put `return false` in the OnTouch event, the item's click event is fired. However, the MouseDown event doesn't fire in OnTouch, preventing swiping back detection (beacuse x1 is always 0).

Comment: However, the two don't work out with each other, as each intercepts the other's events, Can you explain more this line

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin I meant that not all of the events are called completely, since they 'block' each other. Added explanation at the bottom of question. If it still isn't clear, tell me.

Comment: You can use RecyclerView inside ViewPager

Comment: As a start, You need to add just after `NextMonth` and `PreviousMonth` return true, Then you have to log the values to check how is your values calculated and if it is going like what you need in your head or not

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin I added return true where you said. Now both NextMonth and PreviousMonth are called, however you have to click twice on an item for it to get highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

> OnTouch event gets called on the first click, and the OnClick gets called only on the second click

Because `MotionEventActions.Down` and `OnClick`conflict. As a workaround I suggest you to change the background color at the `MotionEventActions.Down` event.

1. Create your own click listener
2. Call the listener when you touch down your items.
3. The listener will callback to `MainActivity` to notify the item changed.
4. At the same time the touch event will called.

I have set the `OnTouchListener` in the viewholder :

```
public class MyViewHolder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder,IOnTouchListener
{
    private TextView textView;
    private MyItemClickListener mListener;
    private Context myContext;
    float x1 = 0;
    float x2 = 0;
    public TextView TextView { get { return textView; } }
    public MyViewHolder(View v, MyItemClickListener mItemClickListener) : base(v)
    {
        textView = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemText);
        mListener = mItemClickListener;
        v.SetOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public MyViewHolder(View v, MyItemClickListener mItemClickListener, Context myContext) : this(v, mItemClickListener)
    {
        this.myContext = myContext;
    }
    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                x1 = e.GetX();
                if (mListener != null)
                {
                    mListener.OnItemClick(v, Position);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                x2 = e.GetX();
                float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > 5)
                {
                    // Left to Right swipe action
                    if (x2 > x1)
                    {
                        NextMonth(v);
                    }

                    // Right to left swipe action               
                    else
                    {
                        PreviousMonth(v);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;           
    }

    public Boolean NextMonth(View v)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(myContext, "NextMonth called", ToastLength.Short).Show();      
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean PreviousMonth(View v)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(myContext, "PreviousMonth called", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Defined the click interface :

```
public interface MyItemClickListener
{
    void OnItemClick(View view, int postion);
}
```

set the click callback in the `MainActivity` to change the background color：

```
  public class MainActivity : Activity,MyItemClickListener
    { 
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        CustomAdapter mAdapter;
        string[] dataSet;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            InitDataSet();
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(dataSet,this);
            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

            //mRecyclerView.SetOnTouchListener(this);
        }

        public void InitDataSet()
        {
            dataSet = new string[60];
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                dataSet[i] = "This is element #" + i;
            }
        }

        public void OnItemClick(View view, int postion)
        {
            mAdapter.NotifyItemChanged(CustomAdapter.selected_position);
            CustomAdapter.selected_position = postion;
            mAdapter.NotifyItemChanged(postion);
        }
     }
   }
```

**Note: Keep your finger move fast, if the speed is slow enough the `MotionEventActions.Down` will not be called.**

[Github souce code](https://github.com/mikexxma/RecyclerView_ItemTouch_Demo)

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your onClick

```
    public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            int position = mRecyclerView.GetChildLayoutPosition((View)sender);
            int oldPosition = selectedPosition;
            selected_position = position;
            // Updating old as well as new positions
            NotifyItemChanged(oldPosition);

            NotifyItemChanged(selected_position);
        }
```

Notice that you have to change the selected position before updating both items

Comment: Thanks. But the problem isn't in the click event. It works fine. The problem is that the OnTouch event gets called on the first click, and the OnClick gets called only on the second click.